# What could lead to [troubleshooting] tag cleanups?

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

What is the point of a [troubleshooting](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/troubleshooting) tag? It's a process, but it does not gain "troubleshooting experts" anything, and the questions are all different areas of Super User. It's way too meta, since almost every question is about *troubleshooting an issue*.

Comment: It's convenient in the sense that most troubleshooting questions aren't a good fit for SU (lots of discussion on meta), so it makes bad questions easy to spot. :-)

Comment: I just came here to ask this exact question... I think a huge amount of questions on SU are about troubleshooting / debugging / call it what you will. I also think a lot of troubleshooting questions ARE a good fit for SU. It all depends on how the question is asked, not the type of question